# “Unable to locate finder for 'pip._vendor.distlib'” error when using "pip install virtualenv"

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, virtualenv

I am trying to install virtualenv with Python 3.6 version under Windows 10.When I run "pip install virtualenv" I'm getting this error. I am a newbie to Python.

```
Collecting virtualenv
  Downloading virtualenv-15.0.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl (3.5MB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 3.5MB 256kB/s
Installing collected packages: virtualenv
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\corey shaw\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "c:\users\corey shaw\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\commands\install.py", line 317, in run
    prefix=options.prefix_path,
  File "c:\users\corey shaw\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_set.py", line 742, in install
    **kwargs
  File "c:\users\corey shaw\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_install.py", line 831, in install
    self.move_wheel_files(self.source_dir, root=root, prefix=prefix)
  File "c:\users\corey shaw\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_install.py", line 1032, in move_wheel_files
    isolated=self.isolated,
  File "c:\users\corey shaw\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\wheel.py", line 493, in move_wheel_files
    maker.make_multiple(['%s = %s' % kv for kv in console.items()])
  File "c:\users\corey shaw\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\distlib\scripts.py", line 383, in make_multiple
    filenames.extend(self.make(specification, options))
  File "c:\users\corey shaw\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\distlib\scripts.py", line 372, in make
    self._make_script(entry, filenames, options=options)
  File "c:\users\corey shaw\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\distlib\scripts.py", line 276, in _make_script
    self._write_script(scriptnames, shebang, script, filenames, ext)
  File "c:\users\corey shaw\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\distlib\scripts.py", line 212, in _write_script
    launcher = self._get_launcher('t')
  File "c:\users\corey shaw\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\distlib\scripts.py", line 351, in _get_launcher
    result = finder(distlib_package).find(name).bytes
  File "c:\users\corey shaw\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\distlib\resources.py", line 324, in finder
    raise DistlibException('Unable to locate finder for %r' % package)
pip._vendor.distlib.DistlibException: Unable to locate finder for 'pip._vendor.distlib'
```

Comment: Yeah I have the same issue, seems like there's something broken with the pip+python3.6 combo. Let's hope it gets fixed before final release

Comment: looks like final release is out, and it's not fixed. :(

Answer (score 80):

1. uninstall current pip:

   ```
   python -m pip uninstall pip setuptools
   ```
2. download `get-pip.py` from https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py
3. execute get-pip script:

   ```
   python get-pip.py
   ```

Comment: It worked for me, maybe there is something wrong with windows python or pip

Comment: The BEST answer I've seen about this issue. Solved this annoying problem on windows 10

Comment: Worked for me while using Python 3.8 64 bit

Answer (score 65):

This worked for me:

**`easy_install --upgrade pip`**

Windows 10, Python 3.6

Comment: Worked for me too

Comment: Good simple solution, but it's great to know why this works, which I think @jjisnow found.

Comment: For those having trouble finding the full path, it's something like this one windows: `c:\Python38\Scripts\easy_install.exe --upgrade pip`

Comment: this is still working for python 3.9 but gives a warning that it will be deprecated in future versions.

Comment: Worked a treat. it did mention that it is being depreciated in future so wonder if they will provide a fix before then. Windows 11 for me.

Answer (score 48):

I will add the solution which worked for me here, in case someone is not able to solve their issue using the above approaches. Open `Terminal` or `Command prompt` or `Anaconda prompt` and follow the 3 steps :

**Step 1** 
Enter `python -m pip uninstall pip`

**Step 2** 
`python -m ensurepip`

**Step 3** 
`python -m pip install -U pip`

The pip version can easily be checked using `pip --version`. Hope this works for you :)

Comment: This worked for me! only I replace step one with @Skyguard 's Step 1

So i did

1) python -m pip uninstall pip setuptools

2) python -m ensurepip

3) python -m pip install -U pip

 and its all solid thank you

Answer (score 9):

Try uninstalling pip and installing get-pip.py. It appears to be a bug in the 3.6 version for Windows. 
https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/3964

It's also reported here.
[pip install jupyter: "Unable to locate finder for 'pip._vendor.distlib'"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39552710/pip-install-jupyter-unable-to-locate-finder-for-pip-vendor-distlib)

Answer (score 2):

Since [Windows now ships with `curl` by default](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/tar-and-curl-come-to-windows/), this one-liner works:

```
pip uninstall pip setuptools && curl -s https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py | python
```

Answer (score 2):

The issue with package `pip._vendor.distlib` persists as of today, even on windows 11 and the latest version of Python 3.10; a workaround that appearantly solves the issue is to force-reinstall `pip` with:

```
python.exe -m pip install --force-reinstall pip --user
```