# I can't upgrade pip on windows 10 EXCEPTION python 3.6.2 pip 7.1.2

Tags: python, opencv, pip

this is what happens when I try to upgrade pip

```
C:\>python -m pip install --upgrade pip
Collecting pip
  Using cached pip-9.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: pip
  Found existing installation: pip 7.1.2
    Uninstalling pip-7.1.2:
      Successfully uninstalled pip-7.1.2
  Rolling back uninstall of pip
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Wesam\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\pip\basecommand.py", line 211, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "C:\Users\Wesam\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\pip\commands\install.py", line 311, in run
    root=options.root_path,
  File "C:\Users\Wesam\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\pip\req\req_set.py", line 646, in install
    **kwargs
  File "C:\Users\Wesam\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\pip\req\req_install.py", line 803, in install
    self.move_wheel_files(self.source_dir, root=root)
  File "C:\Users\Wesam\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\pip\req\req_install.py", line 998, in move_wheel_files
    isolated=self.isolated,
  File "C:\Users\Wesam\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\pip\wheel.py", line 449, in move_wheel_files
    generated.extend(maker.make(spec))
  File "C:\Users\Wesam\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\pip\_vendor\distlib\scripts.py", line 353, in make
    self._make_script(entry, filenames, options=options)
  File "C:\Users\Wesam\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\pip\_vendor\distlib\scripts.py", line 257, in _make_script
    self._write_script(scriptnames, shebang, script, filenames, ext)
  File "C:\Users\Wesam\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\pip\_vendor\distlib\scripts.py", line 193, in _write_script
    launcher = self._get_launcher('t')
  File "C:\Users\Wesam\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\pip\_vendor\distlib\scripts.py", line 332, in _get_launcher
    result = finder(distlib_package).find(name).bytes
  File "C:\Users\Wesam\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\pip\_vendor\distlib\resources.py", line 324, in finder
    raise DistlibException('Unable to locate finder for %r' % package)
pip._vendor.distlib.DistlibException: Unable to locate finder for 'pip._vendor.distlib'
You are using pip version 7.1.2, however version 9.0.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

I don't know how can I actually upgrade pip I have tried several things I found on the web but with no hope

Comment: check this out : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39908406/unable-to-locate-finder-for-pip-vendor-distlib-error-when-using-pip-instal

Comment: So it looks like you're using python 3.6 with windows and pip-7.1.2. It's helpful to provide those details up top

Comment: @GeekyI edited! thank you

Comment: @Adarsh Thank you so much it worked very fine :D

Comment: Oh, I mean at the top of the description, not the question itself