# "RequirementParseError: Expected ',' or end-of-list in gitpython >=2.1.9<2.2 at <2.2"

Tags: python-3.x, installation, pip

I am trying to install "missinglink" using:

```
    python -m pip install missinglink
```

However, I get the error:

```
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\kntsaluba001\AppData\Local\Continuum\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 2851, in _dep_map
    return self.__dep_map
  File "C:\Users\kntsaluba001\AppData\Local\Continuum\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 2685, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError(attr)
AttributeError: _DistInfoDistribution__dep_map

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\kntsaluba001\AppData\Local\Continuum\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\basecommand.py", line 209, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "C:\Users\kntsaluba001\AppData\Local\Continuum\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\commands\install.py", line 310, in run
    wb.build(autobuilding=True)
  File "C:\Users\kntsaluba001\AppData\Local\Continuum\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\wheel.py", line 748, in build
    self.requirement_set.prepare_files(self.finder)
  File "C:\Users\kntsaluba001\AppData\Local\Continuum\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_set.py", line 360, in prepare_files
    ignore_dependencies=self.ignore_dependencies))
  File "C:\Users\kntsaluba001\AppData\Local\Continuum\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_set.py", line 647, in _prepare_file
    set(req_to_install.extras) - set(dist.extras)
  File "C:\Users\kntsaluba001\AppData\Local\Continuum\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 2810, in extras
    return [dep for dep in self._dep_map if dep]
  File "C:\Users\kntsaluba001\AppData\Local\Continuum\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 2853, in _dep_map
    self.__dep_map = self._compute_dependencies()
  File "C:\Users\kntsaluba001\AppData\Local\Continuum\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 2877, in _compute_dependencies
    parsed = next(parse_requirements(distvers))
  File "C:\Users\kntsaluba001\AppData\Local\Continuum\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 2980, in parse_requirements
    "version spec")
  File "C:\Users\kntsaluba001\AppData\Local\Continuum\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 2956, in scan_list
    raise RequirementParseError(msg, line, "at", line[p:])
pip._vendor.pkg_resources.RequirementParseError: Expected ',' or end-of-list in gitpython >=2.1.9<2.2 at <2.2
```

I tried uninstalling gitpython in an attempt to fix the issue, I thought that it would just be reinstalled since its a dependency however I still get the same issue.

Comment: Solved using answer at this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39908406/unable-to-locate-finder-for-pip-vendor-distlib-error-when-using-pip-instal

Answer (score 0):

Consider upgrading pip version. This should solve the issue