# Python pip - Cant update pip

Tags: python, pip

I tried upgrading pip on python version 3.6 but failed
I used this command:

```
python -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

And got this error:

```
C:\Users\home>python -m pip install --upgrade pip
Collecting pip
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/cb/28/91f26bd088ce8e22169032100d4260614fc3da435025ff389ef1d396a433/pip-20.2.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: pip
  Found existing installation: pip 7.1.2
    Uninstalling pip-7.1.2:
      Successfully uninstalled pip-7.1.2
  Rolling back uninstall of pip
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\home\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pip\basecommand.py", line 211, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "C:\Users\home\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pip\commands\install.py", line 311, in run
    root=options.root_path,
  File "C:\Users\home\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_set.py", line 646, in install
    **kwargs
  File "C:\Users\home\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_install.py", line 803, in install
    self.move_wheel_files(self.source_dir, root=root)
  File "C:\Users\home\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_install.py", line 998, in move_wheel_files
    isolated=self.isolated,
  File "C:\Users\home\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pip\wheel.py", line 449, in move_wheel_files
    generated.extend(maker.make(spec))
  File "C:\Users\home\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\distlib\scripts.py", line 353, in make
    self._make_script(entry, filenames, options=options)
  File "C:\Users\home\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\distlib\scripts.py", line 257, in _make_script
    self._write_script(scriptnames, shebang, script, filenames, ext)
  File "C:\Users\home\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\distlib\scripts.py", line 193, in _write_script
    launcher = self._get_launcher('t')
  File "C:\Users\home\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\distlib\scripts.py", line 332, in _get_launcher
    result = finder(distlib_package).find(name).bytes
  File "C:\Users\home\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\distlib\resources.py", line 324, in finder
    raise DistlibException('Unable to locate finder for %r' % package)
pip._vendor.distlib.DistlibException: Unable to locate finder for 'pip._vendor.distlib'
```

Comment: Your traceback implies you're using Python 3.9, not Python 3.6.

Comment: Thanks. I have updated the question. I found out that I cannot upgrade pip from version 7 to 20. This might be the problem why I cannot install any packages

Comment: The traceback is for Python 3.7 now...

Comment: Did you google for the error, anyway? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39908406/unable-to-locate-finder-for-pip-vendor-distlib-error-when-using-pip-instal

Comment: @AKX Thanks AKX. That link solved my problem. I will close this question.

Comment: It seems like you missed to add Python Path to Windows 10 PATH.

Answer (score 0):

easy_install --upgrade pip solved it